# Does Jekyll suport global Markdown reference links?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

If I write a blog post and want to add a link, I do it by using the [link here][tag here], [tag here]: http://addresshere.xyz - format.

Is it possible to just add the [tag here]: http://addresshere.xyz to a reference file and then use the tag without defining it in every post individually? For example, if I want to link to google, I wouldn't have to define the URL in each post, just use the Markdown to tag the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

#### _includes/_links_library.md

```
[google]: https://google.com
[firstPost]: {% post_url 2012-12-31-first-post %}
...
```

You can now include this file in any post and use tags like this :

```
{% include _links_library.md %}

[Go to google][google]
or
[See my first post][firstPost]
```